Inverted Inheritance Structure in Pydantic
I know the normal way of creating Models in Pydantic is by Subclassing and adding fields for example like this:
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Base(BaseModel):
    task_id: str
    task_type: int

class UserCreationTask(Base):
    username: str
    firstname: str
    lastname: str

class  UserInfoTask(Base):
    address: str
    email: str
    phone: str

However I have the following problem. I've defined a set of Models to represent my data in mongodb. These models define all attributes a document can have inside a collection. Following the additive approach as above, I would have to create my DBModels as a union of all request models plus some hidden fields.
I would like to invert this structure. Make the request models inherit from the DB and define fields which should be excluded from everything (both schema generation, schema validation and schema serialization). Basically make it as if it has never been defined.
I haven't found a neat way to do it. I'm not inheriting at the moment and I'm just redefining the fields ad nausium.
class DBTask(BaseModel):
    task_id: str
    task_type: int

    username: str
    firstname: str
    lastname: str

    address: str
    email: str
    phone: str

class ReqUserCreation(BaseModel):
    task_id: str
    task_type: int

    username: str
    firstname: str
    lastname: str

class ReqUserInfo(BaseModel):
    task_id: str
    task_type: int

    address: str
    email: str
    phone: str


I've been able to create the Inverted Inheritance Structure like this:
class Hide(object):
    def __new__(cls):
        if not hasattr(cls, 'instance'):
            cls.instance = super(Hide, cls).__new__(cls)
        return cls.instance


def hide_attributes(cls: Type[BaseModel]):
    for attr_name, attr_type in cls.__annotations__.items():
        if attr_type is Hide:
            cls.__annotations__[attr_name] = Optional[None]
            setattr(cls, attr_name, Field(default=None, exclude=True))
    return cls

class DBTask(BaseModel):
    task_id: str
    task_type: int

    username: str
    firstname: str
    lastname: str

    address: str
    email: str
    phone: str

# Version 4
@hide_attributes
class ResponseTask(DBTask):
    # Version 2:
    address: str = Field(exclude=True)
    email: str = Field(exclude=True)
    phone: str = Field(exclude=True)

    # Version 3
    address: Optional[None] = Field(exclude=True, default=None)
    email: Optional[None] = Field(exclude=True, default=None)
    phone: Optional[None] = Field(exclude=True, default=None)

    # Version 4
    address: Hide 
    email: Hide
    phone: Hide

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # Version 1
        del self.address
        del self.email
        del self.phone

    model_config = ConfigDict(
        populate_by_name=True,
        arbitrary_types_allowed=True,
    )


This works, however the fields are still present in the documentation of the model in FastAPI and the fields are still required in during model_validate

Here the problem is that we still have to provide the Model with the email, phone and address during model_validation. I don't want this to be the case. The fields is no longer in the serialized output as well as the documentation.

This version works but it's very verbose.

This technically works. However the order of operations prevents this from working. The decorator is applied after the parsing? using Pydantic. So even tho the model afterwards has all Attributes of type Hide changed to Optional[None] and it's value set to Field(default=None, exclude=True) but the parsing? of the object with Pydantic has already taken place i.e. Pydantic is applied before the decorator so it still expects all attributes regardless.


Ideally, I want a solution using a decorator that works like the exclude={...}, exclude_none, exclude_unset, include in the model_dump. So my code would look something like this:
@decorator(hide={"address", "email", "phone"})
class SomeModel(SomeDBModel):
    pass

But I'm not sure whether that's possible.

I'd highly recommend to split your db models from your schemas, because of reasons I recently described here. Moreover, by trying to avoid duplication, you make your code less readable, which is an unnecessary sacrifice for your case.

Wouldn't DBTask(UserCreationTask, UserInfoTask) do what you want - i.e. a MixIn for every concept your DBTask should include.

So @VictorEgiazarian what you're suggesting is - don't couple the Layout of the Database with the Request and Response Models. Request and ResponseModels may be coupled but that's spaghetti code and not really nice perse.
The question then is do you go through the effort of using mongodb projections to remove unnecessary data transmission and directly pipe the response into a pydantic response model or do you validate against the db model first and parse the output of that?

What you are trying to do isnt supported currently on pydantic v2, I've seen a lot of grumbling on the forums so likely will get added at some point
Regardless I wouldnt recommend coupling your db models and pydantic validation models, DRY isnt worth the headaches this might cause
but if you were dead set on it then you could do something janky like
def remove_attr(to_remove: list):
    def class_decorator(cls):
        fields = {key: (field.annotation, field.default) for key, field in cls.model_fields.items() if key not in to_remove}
        new_model = create_model(cls.__name__, **fields)
        return new_model

    return class_decorator


class TestModel(BaseModel):
    task_id: str
    task_type: int

    username: str
    firstname: str
    lastname: str

    address: str
    email: str
    phone: str


@remove_attr(["task_id"])
class TestModelCopy(TestModel):
    ...

which just strips the fields from the model, pops the attr you want to remove and creates a new model, which should sidestep any schema FastAPI issues at the cost of a lot of pydantic functionality
